Mathematical symbols \times, \neq,〈 ,〉 is output as 'Γ'
In the following code, symbol 〈 ,〉, \times, \neq are all output as weird letter'Γ'.
How can I correctly output these symbols ?
    \usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage{url,xspace,smfthm} %\usepackage{amsthm} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} \usepackage{mathtools} \usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \usepackage{enumitem}
    
    \DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n} \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58} \DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11} \DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker} \DeclareMathOperator{\〈}{〈} \DeclareMathOperator{\〉}{〉}
    
    \theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{definition}{Definition} \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma} \newtheorem{cor}{Cor} \newtheorem{remark}{remark}
    
    \usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}
    
    
    
    
    
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd} \begin{document}
    
 Let $$ 〈 , 〉_K : \Sha(E/K)\times \Sha(E/K)\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z},
 〈 , 〉_L : \Sha(E/L)\times \Sha(E/L)\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$$ be Cassells-Tate pairing . Then, $〈a, cores(a')〉=〈res(a),a'〉$. 
 $a\neq b, \times b=0$

    
    \end{document}


Don't use $$ especially not if you want to typeset inline math. Use single $...$.

\langle \rangle for inner product symbols.

Also, please try to help others help you and make your code snippet as compilable (and readable) as possible.

If I add your usual \documentclass declaration, your code shows a lot of errors.
Your attempt into making 〈 and 〉 to produce angle brackets is completely wrong, sorry.
Please, be also aware that \Bbb has been deprecated for three decades and that $$ has never be recommended in LaTeX (it's actually discouraged).
\documentclass{smfart}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url,xspace,smfthm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cores}{cores}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}{Cor}
\newtheorem{remark}{remark}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3008}{\TextOrMath{\textlangle}{\langle}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3009}{\TextOrMath{\textrangle}{\rangle}}

\begin{document}
    
 Let
\begin{align*}
〈\ \,,\ 〉_K &: \Sha(E/K)\times \Sha(E/K)\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},
\\
〈\ \,,\ 〉_L &: \Sha(E/L)\times \Sha(E/L)\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
be Cassells-Tate pairing. Then, $〈a, \cores(a')〉=〈\res(a),a'〉$. 
 $a\neq b$, $\times b=0$

\end{document}

Something is missing in front of the last \times, I guess. Note also \res and \cores, which are operators.

